# Inserting string array using for loop in plpgsql

Tags: plpgsql

```
I am trying to insert data into a table using the two input strings. my proc has 2 character varying arrays as inputs. this is my for loop inside the proc.

The two inputs are
p_array character varying[] 
u_array character varying[]
```

code inside proc.
FOREACH i IN ARRAY p_array
LOOP

```
            --08/26/13 -> converted to merge
            RAISE NOTICE 'Value of p_Id: %',p_array(i) ;
            INSERT INTO p_map as d
            (a_pkg,u_pkg)
            VALUES(p_array(i),u_array(i))
                        ON CONFLICT (a_pkg) DO
                            UPDATE 
                            SET 
                            u_pkg = u_array(i);
        
       END LOOP;
```

calling this procedure says success but the values are not inserted into the table. Am i doing anything wrong in for loop?.

Comment: some how it got resolved.  I used

Comment: FOR i in  array_lower( p_array ,1)..array_upper(p__array,1)